# SSH Authentication(no PAM): how to know if user logged in by key or password?

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I want to do something after user SSH logged in, which is different from by public key or by password. PAM won't be involved in my case.

There is one way that the program can check SSH auth information from /var/log/messages or /var/log/auth.log. But usually, those files are unreadable to normal user. Maybe I can chmod o+r, but it sounds insecure.

And I also checked some SSH related environment variables like 'SSH_CONNECTION', but none of them is of use.

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so outside of `sshd` itself, and inside it the only way I know of is by using `authorized_keys` to match specific keys and perform specific commands.

Comment: Thank you. Well, even if I figure out how to implement this, I still need to deal with scp, sftp and etc. as well. Hmm, maybe I am on the wrong direction...

Comment: Besides PAM, any other authentication approach can be supported by SSH?

Comment: ssh only barely supports PAM, actually (complex PAM stacks can interact oddly with it); it strongly prefers to do things itself, and that means the only extensibility it has is via the wonky PAM interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Your only way right now is to change the LogLevel in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and parse your syslog output logs to find out what auth method was used.

LogLevel DEBUG have for sure the info needed, but you can probably find it also with VERBOSE level ... test it